# How to show last unread messages in bold font

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi am creating a `chat` `Application` .I am creating this `Application` using `ReactJs` as frontend and `xmpp` for `message` sending. When the user receives new `mesage` if  its `unread` .I want to show that `latest` message in `bold` `font'. I am storing all the` messages`in`redux store`

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my thought,
How about having each message as an object in redux. Like `{message: '', read: true}`. Based on the `read` flag, if it is false, then add `bold` css class to the message in react